# Build and publish visual studio database project from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have been trying to setup Jenkins to build and publish a visual studio database project. I use the Windows batch command to build the solution using msbuild, which creates a dacpac file. However, when I try to publish using sqlpackage, it fails as Jenkins user doesn't have enough privileges on the database server. What's the right way to go about doing this from here?

1. Change the 'Log On' user for Jenkins from local system account to a service account, that has enough privileges on the database server  ([As mentioned here](http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html))
2. Enter the credentials in plain text within Jenkins build process (I really would hate to do this)

Or is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: Either option #1 or a credentials plugin that allows you to store without using plaintext is the best idea. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin - seems similar to what TFS is doing with TFS 2015 in terms of supporting secure credential storage for build servers

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to run the process as a windows user who has access or you need to put the sql auth settings on the command line - there really isn't any way around it short of writing your own app which calls the DacFx api and decrypts the password from somewhere.

I would run the service as an account that does have persmissions but even that isn't ideal

Answer (score 0):

Its better to go for your choice of 1. Because its one time investment of your effort which doesn't need future maintenance which takes your effort again.